# Using Browserify-shim to require jquery plugins depending on window.jQuery

Tags: jquery, gulp, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm having a really hard time to wrap my head around Browserify-shim to achieve what I want. The doc seems pretty straight-forward, but I must be missing something.

I'm trying to be able to use jquery with `var $ = require('jquery')`(which works fine on its own), but also to be able to use random plugins who refers to a global `window.$` or `window.jQuery` variable.

Here's, for exemple, the plugin I'm trying to use :
https://github.com/jackmoore/zoom

It extends the `$` object with additional methods, and is wrapped in an IIFE, injecting window.jQuery, like this :

```
(function($) {
// stuff
}(window.jQuery));
```

I'm using gulp to bundle my scripts in a simple way, using npm's `browserify`(not the deprecated (`gulp-browserify`) :

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  return browserify('src/scripts/app.js')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));
});
```

And here's the browserify part of my `package.json`file :

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "jquery-zoom": {
      "depends": ["jquery:jQuery"]
    }
  }
```

I'm requiring both `jquery` and `jquery-zoom` in a .js file :

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var zoom = require('jquery-zoom');
```

And the browserify shim diagnostic tool output looks pretty good to me :

```
$ BROWSERIFYSHIM_DIAGNOSTICS=1 browserify -d . -o dist/scripts/app.js

{ file: '/Users/clementoriol/web/browserify-test/src/scripts/app.js',
  info:
   { package_json: '/Users/clementoriol/web/browserify-test/package.json',
     packageDir: '/Users/clementoriol/web/browserify-test',
     shim: undefined,
     exposeGlobals: {},
     browser: undefined,
     'browserify-shim':
      { jquery: '$',
        'jquery-zoom': { depends: [ 'jquery:jQuery' ] } },
     dependencies:
      { jquery: '^2.1.4',
        'jquery-zoom': '^1.7.14' } },
  messages:
   [ 'Resolved "jquery" found in package.json to "/Users/clementoriol/web/browserify-test/jquery"',
     'Resolved "jquery-zoom" found in package.json to "/Users/clementoriol/web/browserify-test/jquery-zoom"',
     'Found depends "jquery" as an installed dependency of the package',
     { resolved:
        { '/Users/clementoriol/web/browserify-test/jquery': { exports: '$', depends: undefined },
          '/Users/clementoriol/web/browserify-test/jquery-zoom':
           { exports: null,
             depends: { jquery: 'jQuery' } } } } ] }
```

But when my script is exectued in the browser, window.jQuery is still clearly undefined.
Any idea what's wrong ?

I made a quick, simple, repository, reproducing my issue :
https://github.com/clementoriol/browserify-shim-test

Thanks !

Comment: Update : Found a way to make it work, by specifiying the paths in my `package.json` file. :                                                                            `"browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "jquery-zoom": "./node_modules/jquery-zoom/jquery.zoom.js"
  }`                                                                                                                         I'm still a bit confused on why I have to specify the paths since those are npm installed modules ?